# Access file in vm from GitHub actions

Tags: github, github-actions

How can I access a file available in a windows vm from GitHub using actions

I am new to GitHub actions and looking for any suggestions and help

Comment: Which VM? your own VM or one hosted by github?

Comment: It’s not hosted by GitHub. It’s an azure vm (windows)

Comment: Are you using a selfhosted runner on that same machine? Then you can just go to that file using the normal way (PowerShell, CMD, etc.)

Comment: No I dont have a self hosted runner